# Sass - Create custom control directive (like @if or @for)

Tags: sass

I'm wondering whether Sass provides a way to create custom *control directive* which is the "@" command like `@if` or `@for`.

I want to make media query syntax looks simpler like:

```
@below 800px {
  ...
}

@above 480px {
  ...
}
```

Currenly I'm using mixin for this which make the code longer:

```
@mixin below($size) {
  @media only screen and (max-width: $size) { @content; }
}

@include below(800px) {
  ...
}
```

So does Sass support this custom control? I can't seem to find solution online.

Note: I don't want to modify the source code.

Thanks

Comment: some stupid jackass downvoted a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Sass does not allow you to create custom control directives.  You would have to modify the Sass parser if you wish to do so or continue using mixins as you are currently already doing.

Comment: @cimmanon Any idea where to start modifying the Sass parser? In my case I'd like to extend the [@at-root node](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/stable/lib/sass/tree/at_root_node.rb), but I don't know how to get Sass to actually create the node when it parses the scss.